# extracting the data from array object

Tags: php, arrays

how to extract or get the data inside this array object? because i got a database error where the data is just an array..

here are the codes..

Welcome.php - controller

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('Crud');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['sc_data'] = $this->select2($username);
    $data2['t_data'] = $this->select($data);
    $this->load->view('quiz', $data2);
}

private function select($data)
{
    $result = $this->Crud->t_select($data);
    return $result;
}

private function select2($data)
{
    $result = $this->Crud->s_course($data);
    return $result;
}
```

crud.php - model

```
public function t_select($data=array())
{
    print_r($data);
    $this->db->select('fac_id');
    $this->db->where('id', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_subjects');
    return $query->result();

}

public function s_course($data = array())
{
    $this->db->select('subject_id');
    $this->db->where('stud_id', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_student_subject');
    return $query->result();
}
```

and this is the error..

Array ( [sc_data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subject_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subject_id] => 3 ) ) )

---

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT `fac_id` FROM `tbl_subjects` WHERE `id` = `Array`

Filename: C:/wamp/www/sample/application/models/crud.php

Line Number: 42

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a 'stud_id' or 'id' with a value that is an array.

You should modify your statements:

```
this->db->where('stud_id', $data);
$this->db->where('id', $data);
```

to select something specific out of '$data'

Answer (score 0):

For converting the std object to array using php code you can to turn your object into a json object, this will return a string of your object to json format.

Take that result and decode with an extra parameter of true, where it will convert to associative array

$array = json_decode(json_encode($stdObject),true);

Comment: where should I put this code sir? into the controller? or into the model?

Comment: You have to put this code on the $data attr.  And after this edit this line:

Comment: After that your print_t function will print you the array in php.  In the array you can get your data like this: foreach $data as $dat{ echo $dat[''subject_id"] ;}

Comment: You cant to do a query to the database  with array this have to be a data as string.

Comment: SELECT fac_id FROM tbl_subjects WHERE id =2

Comment: thank you for helping sir but I still can't get it.. how to put the code in the data attr? sorry for bothering but I am still a student..

Comment: $data=json_decode(json_encode($data),true);$this->db->where('id', $data["subject_id"] );